# Set MapFragment zoom limit

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, zooming

I have an app that uses a Google Map Fragment and i want to set somehow a limit to the zoom level that the user can get to by using the +/- icons provided in the map fragment.

Is there any known way to do this?

**MY SOLUTION:**

```
private final GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener mOnCameraChangeListener =
            new GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
                    Log.d("Zoom", "Zoon: " + cameraPosition.zoom);
                    if (cameraPosition.zoom > 16.01) {
                        getMap().animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(16));
                    }
                }
            };
```

in `onViewCreated()` :

```
//set the zoom limit
getMap().setOnCameraChangeListener(mOnCameraChangeListener);
```

So far this is showing me the zoom level each time the zoom level changes. i am not sure how i can limit the zoom here though... i can't just do `cameraPosition.zoom=15` since it's a final variable.

Any suggestions highly appreciated.

Comment: Use `GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener` and in `onCameraChange(CameraPosition position)` setup logic to restrict the zoom level to certain limit by using `position.zoom`

Comment: I have edited my question, could you please check it out and let me know if you have any suggestion for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot limit zoom as of version 4.0.30 of the API.
There is a pending feature request for that here: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4663

If you cannot wait, you can try to implement something like this: http://youtube.com/watch?v=-nCZ37HdheY
This uses `OnCameraChangeListener` and `GoogleMap.animateCamera`.

Comment: the video kind of looks like what i need, could you please provide me with some implementation details? Because i couldn't find any description to this video.

Comment: @AdrianOlar You may try contacting author of the video. I haven't tried to implement this, but it doesn't look like magic. Some checks and a call to `animateCamera`.

Comment: Indeed it was quite simple, thanks for your reply, i have updated my question:)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the zoom buttons and use your own, where you have more control. Then, you can disable buttons as needed based upon business rules.